# static variable getting reinitialized

Tags: java

I am new to Java. Trying to under static variables. I believe static variables are at class level and will be initialized only once during class loading. However when I run the below program through eclipse, every time the static variable is getting reinitialized. Am I missing something?

```
public class TestClass
{
    private static Map<String,String> map= new HashMap<>(); 

    public void testStatic()
    {
        if(map.get("testkey")==null)
        {
            System.out.println("No values in the Map");
            map.put("testkey","testvalue");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Map has value:"+ map.get("testkey"));
        }
    }
}
```

I am calling the testStatic method from another test class.

```
public class CallTestClass
{
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        TestClass tc= new TestClass();
        tc.testStatic();
    }
}
```

I am assuming that when I call the tc.testStatic(); for the 1st time the static map in TestClass will have no values so it should print "No Values in the map". But if I run the next time it should go to the else part and print  Map has value:testvalue as I am putting value in the previous execution. However, it appears that the map is getting reinitialized every time I invoke the tc.testStatic(); method.

Comment: But your code only calls `testStatic` once? When is the second time?

Comment: When you say "run it a second time", do you mean run the whole program again?  Even static variables are lost when a program ends.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen I am running the CallTestClass twice instead of making two calls in single run. Does it make the TestClass to load twice?

Comment: @GAK: When a process ends, all memory used by it and by extension all data is released and lost. If you want something to persist across process restarts, you have to write it into persistent storage, such as a file or database.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen sorry to bug you.  so instead of running it in eclipse where the program ends  after completion. If I put the TestClass ( after making it as web project) in a web server to keep the program alive and make calls to testStatic from different classes, will they share the same static map?

Comment: @GAK: If your web application platform of choice processes all requests in the same process, the static field would be shared, yes. However that's not a very good thing to rely on because a web application might be run as multiple processes, plus you'd have to be very careful with locking in order to not run into thread safety issues. Plus once you restart your server, the data is gone. A web application platform will likely provide you with better options for shared caching or whatever you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Static variables are initialized only once, at the start of the execution and are lost when a program ends like other variables.

If you want to test your code then call the `testStatic()` method again inside main to see the updated value.

```
public static void main(String... args)
{
    TestClass tc= new TestClass();
    tc.testStatic();
    tc.testStatic();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mutable static variables are evil!!! It makes unit testing very difficult and should be avoided AT ALL COSTS!!.

If you need the map in two places, you should use dependency injection.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>():
    map.put("testkey", "testvalue");
    TestClass1 tc1 = new TestClass1(map);
    TestClass2 tc2 = new TestClass2(map);
    tc1.doStuff();
    tc2.doStuff();
}
```

Note also that `HashMap` is not thread safe so likely won't work for parallel processing

Answer (score 0):

You should call static method 2nd time.

```
public class CallTestClass{
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
    TestClass tc= new TestClass();
    tc.testStatic();  // "No values in the Map"
    tc.testStatic(); // Map has value:testvalue
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create 2 objects of `TestClass` using `new` operator and then invoke `testStatic()` on both of them and see the results. as mentioned in the comments section , do not try to execute the application again, as it will re laod the classes and hence static variables will loose the values set in previous execution.

```
public class CallTestClass {
    public static void main(String... args){
        TestClass object1= new TestClass();
        object1.testStatic(); //this will execute the code inside the if condition, hence map will have an entry for the key "testkey"

        TestClass object2= new TestClass();
        object2.testStatic(); //this will execute the else part. 
        //Even though object is new but as map is defined as 
        // static hence the state set is retained.
    }
}
```

**Edit** As mentioned by another answer below, its a very valid tip, such mutable static variables are evil and must be avoided, instead of these you can inject the map at run time as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/43343979/504133